# Подобрать изображение в зависимости от ширины элемента (компонента)

Tags: javascript, html, изображения, адаптивная-верстка, компоненты

В html есть такой замечательный элемент, как picture, предоставляющий возможность грузить разные изображения в зависимости от медиа-запроса. И все бы хорошо, но проблема появляется при использовании компонентного подхода.

В своем проекте я использую некое подобие component-queries, реализованное с помощью javascript. И это позволяет мне писать css, опираясь на размеры компонента, а не экрана. Хочется сделать так же и для изображений. Например, я пишу `<img data-src="test100.jpg 100px, test200.jpg 200px">`. И далее устанавливается src в зависимости от размера элемента.

Есть ли какие-либо готовые решения для этого?